# Run container as non-root so that the container "root" doesn't map to the running user

Tags: podman

### Question:

How can I use podman to run a container as a non-root such that the root user inside the container is not mapped to the host user running the container?

### Details

In podman, when running a container as non-root, the container root uid (0) is mapped to the host uid, whereas all other uids are mapped according to the `/etc/subuid` file. E.g.:

```
$ grep $USER /etc/subuid
myuser:231072:65536
$ id
uid=1000(myuser) gid=1000(myuser) groups=1000(myuser)

$ podman run --rm -ti  -v /tmp:/tmp --entrypoint='["/sbin/my_init", "--"]' \
>            docker.io/phusion/baseimage:0.11 bash
[...]
*** Running bash...
root@e9f79e3fe659:/# touch /tmp/as_root

root@e9f79e3fe659:/# adduser --gecos '' --disabled-password inneruser
Adding user `inneruser' ...
Adding new group `inneruser' (1000) ...
Adding new user `inneruser' (1000) with group `inneruser' ...
Creating home directory `/home/inneruser' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...

root@e9f79e3fe659:/# setuser inneruser touch /tmp/as_inneruser

root@e9f79e3fe659:/# ls -n /tmp/as_root /tmp/as_inneruser
-rw-r--r-- 1 1000 1000 0 Oct  8 19:20 /tmp/as_inneruser
-rw-r--r-- 1    0    0 0 Oct  8 19:05 /tmp/as_root

root@e9f79e3fe659:/# exit
exit
*** bash exited with status 0.
[...]
*** Killing all processes...

$ ls -n /tmp/as_root /tmp/as_inneruser
-rw-r--r-- 1 232071 232071 0 out  8 16:20 /tmp/as_inneruser
-rw-r--r-- 1   1000   1000 0 out  8 16:05 /tmp/as_root
```

As can be seen above, the container root user was mapped to the uid of the host user running the container (i.e. 1000) so files created by root have `myuser`'s uid (i.e. 1000).

Whereas non-root users inside the container are mapped according to the `subuid` mapping of the running user, i.e.: user `inneruser` inside the container, with uid 1000, was mapped to uid 232071 (231072 + 1000) of the host machine.

### Repeating the Question:

How can I use podman to run a container as a non-root such that the root user inside the container is not mapped to the host user running the container?

I tried passing `--subuidname=myuser` to podman, i.e:

```
$ podman run --subuidname=myuser --rm -ti  -v /tmp:/tmp --entrypoint='["/sbin/my_init", "--"]' \
>            docker.io/phusion/baseimage:0.11 bash
```

But I get this message:

```
Error: error creating libpod runtime: there might not be enough IDs available in the namespace
(requested 231072:231072 for /home/myuser/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/l):
chown /home/myuser/.local/share/containers/storage/overlay/l: invalid argument
```

I would have expected that passing the exact namespace assigned to my user would have the effect of mapping all container uids, including the container root (0) to the set of uids mapped to my user in `/etc/subuid`.

### Technical Details:

The `.config/containers/storage.conf` file was changed from the `vfs` driver to the `overlay` driver using `fuse-overlayfs`, i.e.:

```
[storage]
  driver = "overlay"
  runroot = "/run/user/1000"
  graphroot = "/home/myuser/.local/share/containers/storage"
  [storage.options]
    size = ""
    remap-uids = ""
    remap-gids = ""
    ignore_chown_errors = ""
    remap-user = ""
    remap-group = ""
    ostree_repo = ""
    skip_mount_home = ""
    mount_program = "/home/myuser/bin/fuse-overlayfs"
```

Other than that, it's a standard podman version `1.5.1` installed on Ubuntu 18.04 using the [official PPAs](https://podman.io/getting-started/installation#ubuntu).

Comment: So, which user to you want to map to root user of container?

Comment: @DominiCane: According to the definition of `--subuidname`, I was expecting the first uid of the `myuser` entry in `/etc/subuid` to be the uid that was mapped as root in the container. In the example above, that would be `231072`.

Comment: `podman run --uidmap=0:2:1` ?

Comment: @DominiCare, thanks for the suggestion. It almost worked. The proper incantation that I needed was `--uidmap=0:1:65536`. Basically, the `host_id` parameter in the documentation of `--uidmap` is actually `relative_host_id` when running as non-root, where `0` maps to the user uid, `1` maps to the first uid in `/etc/subuid` for the user (e.g `231072` in the mapping above), `2` maps to the second (e.g. `231073`), etc.

Comment: @LeoRochael you should answer your own question, I'd upvote it.